# Symmetrization of pentadiagonal matrices

Tags: symmetric-matrices, similar-matrices

Unsymmetric tridiagonal matrices $T_3$ can easily be symmetrized via a (diagonal) similarity transformation $D=\text{diag}(d_1, \dots, d_n)$ (i.e. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Similarity_to_symmetric_tridiagonal_matrix))
$$
J_3=D^{-1} T_3 D \,.
$$

Is there a [similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) $P$ for [pentadiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix) matrices $T_5$ such that the transformed matrix 
$$
J_5 = P^{-1} T_5 P
$$ 
is symmetric? Possibly using a lower [bidiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidiagonal_matrix) matrix as $P$?

PS: This post is a double. I also posted this question at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346962).